# Calculating ball.x according to paddle.x movement

Tags: math, lua

I'm working on a simple breakout game and i'm a little bit stuck with the "glue" effect -
the ball hits the paddle, and then sticks in the position where it landed on the paddle. my problem is calculating `ball.x` according to paddle.x movement so it's stays on the same place it landed on paddle.

here's my code:

```
function dragPaddle(event)              
        if event.phase == "began" then
            moveX = event.x - paddle.x
        elseif event.phase == "moved" then
            paddle.x = event.x - moveX

            if glueIsOn == "on" and ballOnGlue == "on" then
                ball.x = (paddle.x - ball.x)
            end
        end
```

Comment: Why don't you do `ball.x = paddle.x`?

Comment: after you move the paddle the ball will always be on center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal thing to do here is work out how much your paddle's position is *changing*, and then modify both the paddle and ball by that amount.  But your code seems to be using a more global approach.

The easiest thing to do in your case is probably to calculate the relative position at which the ball is glued.  Do this *before* updating `paddle.x`:

```
ballDeltaX = ball.x - paddle.x
paddle.x = event.x - moveX
```

Then, if you're glued, you just use the delta again after the paddle position changes:

```
ball.x = paddle.x + ballDeltaX
```